# allocating a box-shadow to one reoccurring element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

my CCS code is

```
.isotope {
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px;
}
```

I've also tried

```
#content .isotope {
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px;
}
```

and

```
.portfolio-wrapper .isotope {
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px;
}
```

but these don't show the box shadow.

The problem is I only want to apply this box shadow to one `div`. The element is a portfolio using a shortcode and is located on a few pages. I only want the box shadow on the portfolio located on the home page. Im struggling to apply it to exactly and only where I want to be, it crops up everywhere!

I'm not very good with HTML and its probably ridiculous to post I really don't know, but in case it can help you help me...

```html
<div id="content" class="portfolio-four">
  <div class="portfolio-wrapper isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 232px;">
    <div class="portfolio-item  isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="project-feed clearfix">
        <div class="ch-item portfolio-4">
          <div class="ch-info portfolio-4">
            <div class="ch-info-front4 ">
              <img src="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/aqua-sana-7-220x161.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="ch-info-back4  portfolio-4" style="background-image:url(http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/aqua-sana-7-220x161.jpg);">
              <div class="info"><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=aqua-sana"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio_details">
        <h3><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=aqua-sana">Aqua Sana</a></h3>
        <div class="tags"><i class="icon-tag"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-item clients projects  isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(228px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="project-feed clearfix">
        <div class="ch-item portfolio-4">
          <div class="ch-info portfolio-4">
            <div class="ch-info-front4 ">
              <img src="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1-32-220x161.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="ch-info-back4  portfolio-4" style="background-image:url(http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1-32-220x161.jpg);">
              <div class="info"><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=center-parcs-2"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio_details">
        <h3><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=center-parcs-2">Center Parcs</a></h3>
        <div class="tags"><i class="icon-tag"></i><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?portfolio_category=clients" rel="tag">clients</a>, <a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?portfolio_category=projects" rel="tag">Projects</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-item bespoke  isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(456px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="project-feed clearfix">
        <div class="ch-item portfolio-4">
          <div class="ch-info portfolio-4">
            <div class="ch-info-front4 ">
              <img src="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/51-220x161.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="ch-info-back4  portfolio-4" style="background-image:url(http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/51-220x161.jpg);">
              <div class="info"><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=bespoke"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio_details">
        <h3><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=bespoke">Bespoke</a></h3>
        <div class="tags"><i class="icon-tag"></i><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?portfolio_category=bespoke" rel="tag">Bespoke</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-item  isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(684px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="project-feed clearfix">
        <div class="ch-item portfolio-4">
          <div class="ch-info portfolio-4">
            <div class="ch-info-front4 ">
              <img src="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1-26-220x161.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="ch-info-back4  portfolio-4" style="background-image:url(http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1-26-220x161.jpg);">
              <div class="info"><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=shop-and-bar-fitting"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio_details">
        <h3><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=shop-and-bar-fitting">Shop and Bar Fitting</a></h3>
        <div class="tags"><i class="icon-tag"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-item bedrooms  isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(912px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="project-feed clearfix">
        <div class="ch-item portfolio-4">
          <div class="ch-info portfolio-4">
            <div class="ch-info-front4 ">
              <img src="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1-15-220x161.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="ch-info-back4  portfolio-4" style="background-image:url(http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/photo-1-15-220x161.jpg);">
              <div class="info"><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=bedrooms"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio_details">
        <h3><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?creativo_portfolio=bedrooms">Bedrooms</a></h3>
        <div class="tags"><i class="icon-tag"></i><a href="http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?portfolio_category=bedrooms" rel="tag">Bedrooms</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You don't need to post entire html/css. Just a simple part with your issue and even better a code snippet or a jsfiddle.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Of course the view is a little messed up, but I copied your css and html into a jsFiddle and it's displaying a shadow:

http://jsfiddle.net/tvp521Lg/

Comment: I'm also getting the shadow around the whole portfolio container on the site itself:

http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?page_id=1280

Comment: Thank you for your replies and @jsve for sorting my post out!

The box shadow does show, which is what i want. The problem is i cant set it to apply to that element alone. If you navigate to:

http://tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk/?page_id=1280

You will see the box shadow - this is what i want to alter, removing the shadow from this location but leaving it active here: [link](tandc.puerteaspecialists.co.uk) (home)

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `<div>` that you want the drop shadow on a unique identifier.

The purpose of a class is to provide an identifier in order to apply a style across multiple elements. The purpose of an `id` is to provide a unique identifier in order to apply a style to a specific element.

So, the straightforward option is to provide a unique id for the `<div>` you are trying to style.

```
<div id="front-page" class="portfolio-wrapper isotope"> ....CODE....</div>
```

Than add the following to your CSS:

```
#front-page .isotope {
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px;
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp for a basic overview on selectors.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was something along these lines. My next problem within this issue is that I am using wordpress and the truth is i dont know where to edit the html code. Would it be saved in header.php? 

next noob question: "....CODE...." - Do i need to add code? or can i just create the div-id and then apply my css to it? i wouldnt know what code to add!

I hope these questions aren't too frustratingly basic but we all gotta start somewhere ay

Comment: Absolutely. Taking those first steps are required of everyone. Depending on the structure of your WordPress site, the html could be in different places. Using search should get you where you need to be (search for <div id="content" class="portfolio-four">). You will not be adding any code apart from `id="yourUniqueID"` into the `<div>` immediately following `<div id="content" class="portfolio-four">`. After that, simply apply your css to it.

Comment: Thanks! So im trying to fill in a few gaps in my head, please correct me if/where i am going wrong:

I am logging into my wordpress dahboard then going to >appearance>editor. Seeing as there is no search option, should i just select each individual .php file and use the "ctrl+F" function to search for something like "<div id="content..." within each one?

Comment: Thanks so much, its really not that intuitive to think that html which forms together so neatly when using the "inspect element" browser function is actually cascade across a variety of .php files! I really had no idea, i thought you were going to say "err no it's located at *insert more intuitive location here*". Anyway thanks so much for clearing that up for me... I guess that's the joy of self design as you know where everything! ill get to searching through my php files now...

update: is this what i was looking for?

`$html .= '<div id="content" class="'.$css_out.'">` ;

Comment: Yes, most likely. You'll want to find the next line that inserts a `<div>` and add your `id=""yourUniqueID"` there.

Comment: ok last, last thing on topic, is this what i am looking for and what should i edit it to? cheers a million

 endif;
   endif;
  endif; 
  $html .= `'<div class="portfolio-wrapper">';` 
        
      $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'creativo_portfolio',
                            'paged' => 1,

Comment: Without actually looking at your code I can't say for sure. See if you can find `<div class="portfolio-wrapper isotope"`. If you can, change it to `<div id="yourUniqueId" class="portfolio-wrapper isotope"`. If you can't find it, you might have to poke around near `class="portfolio-wrapper"`

Comment: i changed `'<div class="portfolio-wrapper">';` to `'<div id="myDIV" class="portfolio-wrapper">';` and then refered to it(`#myDiv .isotope {`). Now i have exactly what i want, box shadow on the home page but not on the Projects tab, so chuffed, thank you so much for you time and help, unfortunately you lastest comment has confused me again, but thats just the way it is with coding (for me at least) a constant battle with confusion and evolving problems, that jsut happen to be oh so sweet to solve. Haha, couldnt have done it without you!

Comment: Excellent, happy to have helped.  Don't forget to mark your questions as answered when you are satisfied with them.

Comment: EDIT: must have refreshed to fast, the box shadow has now disappeared from the home page also... argghhhhh, i guess ill read further into your penultimate comment...

Comment: Haha, that's frustrating. But keep it up, starting out it really just takes perseverance. What theme are you using?

Comment: Sorry! i am using Creativo theme, i found an option in the WYSIWYG editor that allows to add a class to specific rows or columns so i managed to get the desired effect without having to directly edit code. I still wish i knew where to find what i was looking for as its annoying when things that obviously must, just dont seem to make sense.